# Compare single object across JSON array nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, compare

If I have the below json data for example, how would I compare this array to return true based on a single element of the array?
In this example, Id like true to be returned as the url's are all the same, ignoring all other objects. However if one of the url's were different false should be returned.

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "c",
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
  }
]
```

I have tried to use a filter to take only the url object and then compare that, however that hasn't worked.
Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What was your 'filter' implementation? Have you tried implementing this comparison using a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not nearly as elegant as the .every() approach, but it's good to show different ways of approaching array iterations

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "a",
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "b",
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "c",
    url: "http://www.google.co.uk"
  }
]

function urlsAreIdentical(arr) {
  let theurl, urlsAreTheSame = true;
  arr.forEach(obj => {
    if (!theurl) theurl = obj.url;
    else if (theurl != obj.url) urlsAreTheSame = false;
  })
  return urlsAreTheSame;
}

console.log(urlsAreIdentical(data));

data.push({
  id: 4,
  name: "c",
  url: "http://www.yahoo.co.uk"
});


console.log(urlsAreIdentical(data));
```

Comment: while I like the simplicity of the every() method, this is the method I went with and. it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the "every" method to check that.

You could get the url of the first position and check with that if the whole array satisfy your condition.

```
const firstUrl = yourArray[0].url;
const allUrlsAreTheSame = yourArray.every(item => item.url === firstUrl);
```